# Exclude database form AG Backup

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Is it possible to exclude a database from an availability group backup?

My backup jobs looks like this:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES'
@URL= xxx,
@Credential = xxx,
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = NULL,
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen on ola's [Site](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html), you can exclude backups by adding `, -database`.

An example of this:

> USER_DATABASES, -Db1  All user databases, except Db1

Or in you case, with ag databases:

> AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES, -Db1 All availability group databases, except Db1

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'AVAILABILITY_GROUP_DATABASES, -Db1'
@URL= xxx,
@Credential = xxx,
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = NULL,
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y'
```

Comment: Yes, this is how to do it. By the way, if you are on SQL Server 2016 or later I recommend that you use a Shared Access Signature when doing backup to URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-2017